# Hosting two websites on single Azure VM and exposing ports

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure Linux VM that runs two web sites. On port 80 and 8080. I'm going to add domains to both the sites and when the domains are mapped I don't want the user to specify the port (for example 8080). Meaning there should be two public endpoints.

What service in Azure can I use for getting this done?

Comment: You can setup CDN with multiple end points with different host names that has different origin ports apart from 80,443. CDN is costly, but Azure CDN also supports free SSL certificate so it is worth the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a reverse proxy. Azure Load balancer can do this for you.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/load-balancer/

Answer (score 0):

no service on azure can help you with that. the default for http is port 80. you are looking for is called host headers. Without knowing what you are using its impossible to assist further, but articles for configuring iis\apache\another_common_webserver are abundant.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at application gateway. It can host multiple sites on the same IP, so in theory this should work if the back-end is running on a different port, see below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-multisite-portal

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it Azure Load Balancer. I'm sure many other services can be used to do that as well. [This is how I did it](http://meetkamal.today/index.php/2017/10/13/hosting-two-sites-azure-vm-load-balancer/).